# A particularly tricky integral: $ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{3}{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} dx. $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, definite-integrals

I encountered the following, deceptively simple looking integral -

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{3}{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} dx. $$

My goal was to hopefully somehow use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem; I've tried every elementary bound that I can think of to no avail. One approach suggested to me is to write

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} - \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}dx, $$
then try and use an induction and partial fraction decomposition argument. Doing this, I didn't find anything useful.

When I tried plugging into wolfram/mathematica I got roughly the behavior (this could be wrong, so take it with a grain of salt) 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} dx =  {}_2 F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}, n, \frac{3}{2}, -1\right). $$

Other calculations by trying to play with Gaussian bounds led to the result $ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} $ but this was done on a computer, not with an explicit method. There's also been some hints from mathematica that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{3}{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} dx $$ is somehow related to $$ \sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma(n)}. $$

I believe that there is an elementary argument and that I just haven't found it. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Substitute $x=y/\sqrt{n}$ and apply DCT.

Comment: Thanks! That's slick. I like it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the change of variable $y = n^{1/2} x$ you get
$$
n^{3/2} ∫_0^1\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n}}\,\mathrm{d}x = ∫_0^{n^{1/2}}\frac{y^2}{(1+n^{-1}y^2)^{n}}\,\mathrm{d}y \underset{n\to\infty}{⟶} ∫_0^\infty y^2e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
by dominated convergence. Now, do the change of variable $x = y^2$ to get
$$
∫_0^\infty y^2e^{-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{2}∫_0^\infty x^{1/2} e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{2} = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the details added. I knew this was way simpler than I was making it out to be.

Answer (score 3):

For large $n$ the integrand decreases rapidly away from $x=0$, so instead of integrating from $0$ to $1$ we may integrate from $0$ to $+\infty$.  According to Maple
$$ \eqalign{\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\; dx &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \;\Gamma(n-3/2)}{4\; \Gamma(n)} \cr
&\sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} n^{-3/2} + \frac{15 \sqrt{\pi}}{32} n^{-5/2} + \ldots}$$

Comment: Yes, we were able to get something along these lines as well. We were wondering if there's an explicit elementary way of doing so. But thanks for verifying that this is the right looking answer!

Comment: Provable with $x=\tan t,\,y=\sin^2t=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Another approach would be to use Watson's lemma after a change of variable $t = \ln(1+x^2)$.